# passing jsp variable of a $ function() to a java class function as argument: how treat taglib code

Tags: jsp, taglib, usebean

I have written an insert function with taglibs in jsp in a $ function () which uses this code for calling it in a java script:

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="insertEdge"/>
                    ${tf:insertEdge(obj, stateid)}
```

I know that my code of insert methods works right, but I don't know why the var stateid while it has a value in java scrip section it doesn't have value in called method. What is wrong? 
how can I find the point of error?

Comment: Javascript variables cannot be used inside Expression Language.

Comment: Thanks, but i have javascript variables and I should pass them to codes that they are in java; my code of insertion in table of mySQL is java based. How can I pass the variables to java code of connection to database?

Comment: actually, working on client side variables to send a database on server, even with ajax, is not a good idea; thank you